# Magento 2.3.3 declarative schema column type json

Tags: magento2.3, declarative-schema

I want to create One table model using declarative schema having one column type as json.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" ?>
<schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/schema.xsd">
    <table comment="levosoft_partpicker_imagetags Table" engine="innodb" name="levosoft_partpicker_imagetags" resource="default">
        <column comment="Entity Id" identity="true" name="imagetags_id" nullable="false" padding="6" unsigned="true" xsi:type="smallint"/>
        <constraint referenceId="PRIMARY" xsi:type="primary">
            <column name="imagetags_id"/>
        </constraint>
        <column xsi:type="int" name="entity_id" padding="10" unsigned="true" nullable="false" identity="false"
                default="0" comment="Entity ID"/>
        <column name="tags_json" nullable="true" xsi:type="json"/>
        <index referenceId="INDEX_PARTPICKER_PRODUCT" indexType="btree">
            <column name="entity_id"/>
        </index>
        <constraint xsi:type="foreign" referenceId="TEXTMIMEDI_PAARTPICKER_IMAGETAGS_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ENTT_ID"
                    table="levosoft_partpicker_imagetags" column="entity_id" referenceTable="catalog_product_entity"
                    referenceColumn="entity_id" onDelete="CASCADE"/>
    </table>
</schema>
```

I captured following error:-

```
/var/www/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Setup/Declaration/Schema/SchemaConfig.php:82:
string(412) "The XML in file "/var/www/public_html/app/code/Levosoft/Partpicker/etc/db_schema.xml" is invalid:
Element 'column', attribute '{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance}type': The QName value 'json' of the xsi:type attribute does not resolve to a type definition.
Line: 9
```

The error shows that yet magento had not added support for json type.

```
Any proper work around? Other then I `alter type later via sql`
```

fmi:
To check declarative schema is working properly you have to run following command:

```
php bin/magento setup:db-declaration:generate-whitelist --module-name=Textmimedia_Partpicker
```

If no error in script it will generate whitelist file else no error will be displayed & file not generated.
To check its error you have to update following code in core file (`/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Setup/Declaration/Schema/SchemaConfig.php`) for testing:

```
public function getDeclarationConfig()
    {
        try {
        $schema = $this->schemaFactory->create();
        $data = $this->readerComposite->read(FileResolverByModule::ALL_MODULES);
        $this->declarativeSchemaBuilder->addTablesData($data['table']);
        $schema = $this->declarativeSchemaBuilder->build($schema);
        return $schema;
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            var_dump($e->getMessage());exit;
        }
    }
```

SOLUTION EXPECTED IS: HOW TO ADD THIS OPTION IN MAGENTO2.3

Answer (score 4):

Magento does not support json type out of the box. You can check all supported types at **vendor/magento/framework/Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/schema.xsd**

actually you don't need json type, ofc it's much more easier make all checks of data consistency on db side, but you can create a column with **LONGTEXT** and before save, add verification on php level (cast to/from json) or use specific mysql json functions **https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html**

Comment: Completely agree with data suggestion

Comment: Completely Disagree with your point. I know this when this field is not their we do like that but this is not proper work around. In past also face a lot issues due to longtext or blob field type to store json. If Mysql is giving this option then this option should be in Mageto Latest versions as well.

Comment: purpose of this question is to add PROPER Customization for this issue to add JSON field into the magento2. Not the other work around. thanks

Comment: @HassanAliShahzad https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Feature-Requests-and/idb-p/feature-requests

Answer (score 2):

JSON format is supported in Magento 2.4.0
I tested it myself:

```
 <table name="xxxx">
        <column xsi:type="json" name="xxxxx" comment="Comment for xxx field"/>
    </table>
```

Comment: Question is related to M2.3 not M2.4

Answer (score 0):

Note: It seems this is now supported in Magento 2.4.0.

So something like this possibly:

```
<column xsi:type="json" name="json" nullable="true" comment="Json"/>
```

> **JSON field support** MySQL 5.7 supports the native JSON data type: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html. Magento 2.4.0 now
> supports using JSON fields with a declarative schema.
> See: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/release-notes/backward-incompatible-changes/#json-field-support

Note: This of course depends on DB support.
MariaDB 10.2.7 has a JSON alias for LONGTEXT, https://mariadb.com/kb/en/json-data-type/

Unfortunately I have not managed to get it to work yet as the DB version we are using at present is a little bit older so will just use text for now...

Comment: Question is related to M2.3 not M2.4

Answer (score 0):

I have created a patch for 2.3 based on the commits used for 2.4

Here are the commits:
https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/25479

here is a link to the patch:

https://gist.github.com/willboudle/4fb62bac2ed895bb0172202e6288ee74